# What are the reasons to return value false of System.Web.HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In `websocket` programming I am getting the value of `IsWebSocketRequest` false.   ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍

I want to know why it is returning value `false`.    ‍      ‍      ‍
Here's my JavaScript code.   ‍      ‍      ‍

```
$('#openButton').click(function() {

    try {

        username = $('#txtuserid').val();
        var url = "ws://" + window.location.host + '/api/Values?userid=' + username;
        demoService = new WebSocket(url);
        console.log(url);
        demoService.onopen = function() {
            $('#divmsg').append('Connection Opened <Br/>');
        }

        demoService.onmessage = function(message) {
            var md = message.data;
            if (md.substring(0, 5) == 'user:') {
                $('#txloginuser').val(md.replace('user:', ''));
            } else if (md.substring(0, 4) == 'key:') {
                $('#txuserkey').val(md.replace('key:', ''));
            } else {
                $('#divmsg').append(message.data + "<br/>");
            }
        }

        demoService.onclose = function() {
            try {
                $('#divmsg').append("Connection Closed" + "<br/>");
                $('#txloginuser').val('');
                $('#txuserkey').val('');
                $('#txuserid').val('');
                $('#divmsg').empty();
            } catch (ex) {
                alert(ex);
            }
        }


        demoService.onerror = function(error) {
            $('#divmsg').append(error.data + "<br/>");
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
});
```

I want a successful websocket connection. Can someone help me please?
Thank you